# Enlazar archivos con RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview

necesito listar el contenido de mi carpeta raw, mi problema es que no sé como enlazarlos utilizando el RecyclerView, he probado pasándole una lista de strings con un for y no hay problema, pero necesito que la lista sean los archivos que tengo en mi carpeta raw. Alguien que me ayude?

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

      ArrayList<String> lista;
      RecyclerView recycler;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      recycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RecyclerId);
      recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));
          
      lista = new ArrayList<String>();

      for (int i = 0; i <= 10;i++){

           lista.add("Dato # "+i+" ");
      }

      AdapterDatos adapter = new AdapterDatos(lista);
      recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeramente crea un método para obtener los archivos que se encuentran dentro del directorio `/raw`:

```
public Field[] getListRaw(){
    Field[] allFiles=R.raw.class.getFields();
    return allFiles;
}
```

Usa este método para obtener los nombres y agrégalos a el `ArrayList` con el que configuras tu Adapter:

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

          ArrayList<String> lista;
          RecyclerView recycler;

          @Override
          protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

          recycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RecyclerId);
          recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));
          
          lista = new ArrayList<String>();

          for (int i = 0; i <= 10;i++){

               lista.add("Dato # "+i+" ");
               }

          /*---Agrega nombres de archivos en Raw.---*/
          Field[] listaRaw = getListRaw();
          for(Field archivo : listaRaw){
              lista.add(archivo.getName());
          }
          /*---------------------------------------*/

          AdapterDatos adapter = new AdapterDatos(lista);
          recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
 }
```

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias !!